# How to apply Python library in Spark computations?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to use this Python library called [traces](https://github.com/datascopeanalytics/traces) on my Spark RDDs that contain time series data. In other words, I have data in RDDs (100 partitions), and I would like to apply the code so that it computes the results in parallel as Spark was meant for. Specifically, I am trying to transform unevenly-spaced times series data to evenly-spaced representations.

In summary, I am asking

1. How to apply the Python package to Spark RDD partitions in
   parallel?
2. Since the [traces](http://traces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package computes correlations for time series data, would achieving the above task result in the correct answer if the data are in partitions?

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly you want to achieve. Little more info would help. If you need to use python library on a RDD you should have the python library installed (or in PYTHONPATH) in all slaves.

Comment: @Himaprasoon I just added some clarifications. I am looking to transform unevenly-spaced times series data to evenly-spaced representations